# Long enough vertical bar | depending on expression before and after it - Elliptic integral

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to write an elliptic integral `F(\phi|k^2)` with different expressions for `\phi` and `k^2` including fractions. So I want a new command (macro?) for this. It should look like e.g. `\F{\phi}{k^2}`.
This is no problem at all, without scaling the vertical bar `|`. But I want to autoscale it with the arguments.

What can I do to create a new command like this? Do I have to go the long way by trying to determine the height of the arguments? How would this look alike?

Comment: I suggest that you have a look to the `mathtools` package, subsection 3.6.  **Edit:** “fractals”?  Or do you mean “fractions”?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Yes, you are right, sorry - edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @GustavoMezzetti's comment, here's a solution that makes use of the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` macro of the `mathtools` package.

[image]

Aside: You may want to come up with a mnemonic macro name than "`\F`".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% See p. 27 of the user guide of the 'mathtools' package
% for the source of the following code
\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{%
   \nonscript\:#1\vert
   \allowbreak
   \nonscript\:
   \mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\PSet[1]\lparen\rparen{% 
   \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}#1}
\newcommand\F[2]{F\PSet*{#1\given #2}}

\begin{document}
\[  
\F{\phi}{k} \quad  \F{\phi}{k^2} \quad \F{\phi}{\frac{u}{v}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @egreg has pointed out in comment, using `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` in the definition of the `\F` macro may be sort of overkill, as no use is made of the optional argument to specify fixed-sized fences. A more streamlined version of the `\F` macro would therefore be:

```
\newcommand{\F}[2]{%
   F\mleft(#1\nonscript\:\middle\vert\nonscript\:‌​#2\mright)}
```

With this approach, it's necessary to load the `mleftright` package for its `\mleft` and `\mright` macros. On the other hand, it's no longer necessary to load the `mathtools` package.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright} % for "\mleft" and "\mright" macros
\newcommand{\F}[2]{%
   F\mleft(#1\nonscript\:\middle\vert\nonscript\:‌​#2\mright)}
\begin{document}
\[
\F{\phi}{k} \quad  \F{\phi}{k^2} \quad \F{\phi}{\frac{u}{v}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why doing all that work, when at the end you always use the “expanding” version. Just `\newcommand{\F}[2](F\mleft(#1\nonscript\:\middle\nonscript\:#2\mright)}` would do the same (with `mleftright`).

Comment: @egreg - I'm afraid I get a cryptic `Missing \begin{document}` when I try to implement your approach. (Yes, I do load the `mleftright` package.)

Comment: Typo: ( instead of { before F

Comment: @egreg - Thanks! I've posted an addendum to post your suggestion, fixing a second issue along the way (missing `\vert` after `\middle`).

Comment: Allow me to recall [my point of view](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336103) on how such constructions should be implemented in order to get the correct spacing in all situations (inserting a suitable combination of math atoms, instead of relying on explicit space commands).

Answer (score 4):

A simple implementation with a perhaps more natural syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\EllInner}[1]{(}{)}{%
  \renewcommand{\with}{\,\delimsize|\,}%
  #1%
}
\newcommand{\Ell}{F\EllInner}
\providecommand{\with}{}

\begin{document}

\[
\Ell{\varphi\with k^2} = \int_0^\varphi\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^4\sin^2t}}
\qquad
\Ell*{\frac{\pi^2}{4}\with k^2}
\qquad
\Ell[\Big]{\frac{\pi^2}{4}\with k^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the two argument syntax, you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\EllInner}[2]{(}{)}{%
  #1\,\delimsize|\,#2%
}
\newcommand{\Ell}{F\EllInner}

\begin{document}

\[
\Ell{\varphi}{k^2} = \int_0^\varphi\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^4\sin^2t}}
\qquad
\Ell*{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{k^2}
\qquad
\Ell[\Big]{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{k^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can also use `|` as the inner separator, with a slick trick. The *caveat* is that the expressions must not contain `|`, but they can contain `\vert`, `\lvert` or `\rvert`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\EllInner}[1]{(}{)}{\activatebar #1}
\newcommand{\Ell}{F\EllInner}
\newcommand{\activatebar}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`| \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\,\delimsize\vert\,}%
  \mathcode`|="8000
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Ell{\varphi | k^2} = \int_0^\varphi\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^4\sin^2t}}
\qquad
\Ell*{\frac{\pi^2}{4} | k^2}
\qquad
\Ell[\Big]{\frac{\pi^2}{4} | k^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also with `mathtools`, I define a `\Fell`command with `DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` which  takes `two` arguments. The `\Fell*` command adds a pair of implicit `\left···\right`, and the optional argument in `\Fell` (`\big, \Big`,  &c.) allows to fine-tune the size of the delimiters.

A variant which relies on `xparse`, named `\fell`, uses only `one` argument in two parts separated by a semicolon, so the syntax is closer to what one writes by hand.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Fell[2]{\mathrm{F}}(){}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}

\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\Fel}[1]{\mathrm{F}}(){}%
{\Felargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Felargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\Felargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Felargsaux}{mm}
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}%

\begin{document}

 \[ \Fell{\varphi}{ k^2} = \int_0^\varphi\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu t}{\sqrt{1-k^4\sin^2t}}\qquad\Fell*{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{k^2} \qquad\Fell[\Big]{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{k^2}
  \]%

\[ \Fel{\varphi ; \ell} = \int_0^\varphi\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu t}{\sqrt{1-\ell^2\sin^2t}}\qquad\Fel*{\frac{\pi^2}{4}; \ell}\qquad\Fel[\Big]{\frac{\pi^2}{4}; \ell}
  \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]