# Space around vertical bar/pipe

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical, bar

I am new to Latex and am giving it a try on a homework assignment.  My professor's notes (which are written in Latex) include a formula that looks like this:

[image]

When I try and recreate this formula using Latex, my version looks like this:

[image]

There are a few differences between these two renderings, but the one that is bothering me most is that my professor's pipe character (`|`) has a comfortable amount of horizontal white space on either side; my pipe has very little space surrounding it.

How can I make my pipe character look like my professor's?  Is he using a different character than I am?

Here is the code I am using:

```
\[
  E_1 =  \big\{ \langle 5, j \rangle \big| j \in \{1, \cdots, n \} - \{ 5 \} \big\}
\]
```

Comment: `\mid`  is the command for `|`  used as an infix operator.  Note also `big\{` should be `\bigl\{` and `\big\}` should be `\bigr\}` or you lose the open/close spacing on the delimiters

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - `\mid` was what I was looking for!  Thanks!  If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I already did:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Also, I converted the `\big`s to `\bigl` and `\bigr`, but didn't notice a difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Do you know about the tools offered by the `\mathtools` package?  If not, you might want to have a look to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336080) and to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333471).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\mid`  is the command for `|`  used as an infix operator.  Note also `big\{` should be `\bigl\{` and `\big\}` should be `\bigr\}` or you lose the open/close spacing on the delimiters, however unfortunately you can't use the `\bigm` variant with `\mid` as it isn't a delimiter so you need `\bigm|` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

aaa
\[
  E_1 =  \{ \langle 5, j \rangle \mid j \in \{1, \cdots, n \} - \{ 5 \} \}
\]

bbb
\[
  E_1 =  \bigl\{ \langle 5, j \rangle \bigm| j \in \{1, \cdots, n \} - \{ 5 \} \bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GuM I'm getting too old for this:-)

Answer (score 3):

I propose to define macros `\set` and `\innerp` with packages `xparse` and `mathtools`, using a simple syntax: `\set{x;P(x)}` and `\innerp{x,y}`.

These commands have a starred version, which adds a pair of implicit `\left \right` in front of the delimiters and ensures a proper spacing. They also can have as an optional argument one of `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg`, which similarly adds a pair of implicit `\bigl \bigr`, &c.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
%%% Syntax: \set{x ; P(x)})
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\mathopen{} #2\nonscript\,}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\innpargs{#1}}
%%% Syntax: \innerp{x,y}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{ m m }
 {#1\:,\,\mathopen{}#2}%

\begin{document}

\[
  E_1 = \set*{ \innerp{5, j} ; j \in \set{1, \cdots, n } - \set{5} }
\]

\[
  E_1 = \set[\Big]{ \innerp{5, j} ; j \in \set{1, \cdots, n } - \set{5} }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]